# Ionic splash screen (error: unable to read uploaded image)

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to use the ionic resources --splash command, I have a splash.png file saved in my resources folder as well as in the root of my ios and android folders, and it is 2208 x 2208 which is the advised size. But when I run the command I get the following error

"Invalid upload: unable to read uploaded image"

I have added the splash screen preference in my config.xml. Is there more conditions that they didn't specify?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the following blog post? http://ionicframework.com/blog/automating-icons-and-splash-screens/ and the part from the docs? http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/icon-splashscreen.html

Comment: Yes, those are the docs i've been following. I should have specified that I had it working previously and this has only been happening since i've been trying to replace my old splash screen with a new one. @QueryLars

Comment: Hey... I created this repo to automate both icon and splash screen generation github.com/dericeira/Icon-Splash-Resize

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just realized that the image I had was actually an Adobe Illustrator image. All I had to do was rename the image from .png to .ai and it worked!

For those wondering here is a quick explanation on the difference between the two:

.ai - Adobe Illustrator vector files are scalable both down and up.

.png - pixel files can be scaled down, not up.

Answer (score 17):

I got the same error when uploading an interlaced .png.

However after re-exporting with **interlacing turned off** ionic accepted the file fine.

Answer (score 4):

Do not try to save your original jpeg image into png by changing the name of it. You have to use png image. For instance, I save my jpeg images into the ionic folder, and change the type of the jpeg file by  changing .jepg to .png. However, it doesn't make a real png image. You have to use software to do the type transferring or download the png image.

Comment: @Panther because just change the name and property of the file doesn't make a true png file

Comment: @Panther OK, I will describe it

Comment: @Panther, yeah, i understand that, i will make the change, it's that the answer i wrote it on my phone, so I didn't make it more clear. Next time, I will give an answer adding some procedures.

Answer (score 0):

I had it working in Windows 7 by storing the icon and splash files as psd.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I was doing wrong:

1 - Renaming a `.jpg` to `.png` and hope it works, it didn't. You **need** to use a `.png` image.

2 - Using an image with incorrect resolution, most articles mention that it has to be 2208*2208, I kept getting errors for an incorrectly sized image. Using a **2732 * 2732** resolution image worked like a charm.