# Ionic cordova resources splash screen not working

Tags: cordova, ionic3, splash-screen

I am trying to use the automatic method created by Ionic to generate matched sized splash screen sizes to my app.

I am using the next command for it:

```
ionic cordova resources
```

Or:

```
ionic cordova resources --splash
```

(for more specific command).

Then I receive the next error in the CLI:

```
✖ Uploading source images to prepare for transformations - failed!
HTTP Error 400: POST https://res.ionic.io/api/v1/upload

{"Error":"unable to read uploaded image","Width":0,"Height":0,"Type":"png","Vector":false}
```

I have tried to upload either `png` and `jpg`.
I have also tried to clear the transparency of the `png` so it will have background. I have also tried using varies of sizes taken from Apple official website.
But still it does not work.

Maybe something in the image is incorrect?

Btw, Icon just works fine.

Comment: have to ask...sorry,, the image is named correctly and placed in resources folder right?

Comment: The image named: "splash.png" and placed in "resources" directory.

Comment: related https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/495 also https://stackoverflow.com/a/31399846/4826457

Comment: I did not find anything help in this link

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem the other day, and I found a solution

https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/3385#issuecomment-408508772

First, add the Android platform:

```
ionic cordova platform add android
```

Get ready `icon.png` and `splash.png` in `resources`

Run

```
npm i -g ionic@4.1.0-testing.458303e0
```

Then `ionic cordova resources android`

Answer (score 1):

change the `.png` extension to `.ai` 
It should work

Answer (score 0):

Saving the image through `Windows Paint` solved the problem. Now Cordova successfully recognize the image width and height.

Answer (score 0):

Image file needs to be in non-interlaced format.  Use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) or another [tool](http://resizeimage.net/) to save it as non-interlaced and retry.

Answer (score 0):

Save files as icon.psd and splash.psd (Photoshop format) with Gimp.

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure that the *icon size* is at least **1024 x 1024px** and the ***splash screen size*** is at least **2732 x 2732px**.